# How to know when the feathers-client is connected to a service

Tags: feathersjs

I'm trying to test an event filter however there's a timing issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. Other than wrapping the REST request in a `setTimeout`, how could I get this working?

```
const app = require('../../src/app');

const feathers = require('feathers/client')
const socketio = require('feathers-socketio/client');
const hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const rp = require('request-promise');

const service = app.service('users');

let server = null;

describe('\'users\' service', () => {
  beforeEach((done) => {
    server = app.listen('3030');
    server.once('listening', done);
  });

  afterEach((done) => {
    server.close(done);
  });

  it('returns stuff #test', (done) => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3030');
    const app = feathers()
      .configure(hooks())
      .configure(socketio(socket));

    const messageService = app.service('users');
    messageService.on('created', message => {
      console.log('Created a message', message);
      done();
    });

    socket.on('connection', () => {
      // 
      // The messageService is not connected yet
      //   so messages.filters.js will not fire
      // 
      // Giving it a chance to connect with setTimeout does work... 
      //           setTimeout(() => {
        rp({
          method: 'POST',
          url: 'http://localhost:3030/users',
          body: {
            test: 'Message from REST'
          },
          json: true
        });
      //           }, 500);
    });

  });
});
```

I have tried replacing the `socket.on` with these as well:

- `messageService.on('connection'`
- `service.on('connection'` (based on Node.js EventEmitter)
- and so on...

**Edit**

I have since found `service.on('newListener'` works however it is being triggered many times.  I need to track down the single connection:

```
const messageService = app.service('users');
messageService.on('created', message => {
  console.log('Created a message', message);
  done();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `service.on('newListener'`.

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener

> Listeners registered for the 'newListener' event will be passed the event name and a reference to the listener being added.

However, when I implemented this I found that it is listening to 5 different events. So, you need to filter those down:

```
service.on('newListener', (event, listener) => {
  if (event === 'created') {
    rp({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3030/users',
      body: {
        test: 'Message from REST'
      },
      json: true
    });
  }
});
```